# If then else if type to seperate methods

Tags: java, types

I have a method like this:

```
//in Constant class
MathObject add(MathObject addend){
    if (addend instanceof Constant)
    {
        return new Constant(this.c + addend.c);
    }
    if (addend instanceof Variable)
    {
        return new Sum(this, addend);
    }
    //...
}
```

I would like to convert that structure into something like this:

```
//in Constant class
Constant add(Constant addend){
    return new Constant(this.c + addend.c);
}

Addition add(Variable addend){
    return new Sum(this, addend);
}
//...
```

This way the right method for each object would be found in a more structured way, more important the actual return type is known.
The problem is that for some cases, such as an addition with `Product` and a `Variable` it is unknown whether the returned object will be an `Addition` or a `Product`, like this:

```
//in Variable class
MathObject add(Product addend){
    if (addend.contains(this))
    {
        //code
        return new Product(newArray);
    }
    else
    {
        return new Sum(this, addend);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I use such type specific operations (i.e. `add(Constant)`, not `new Sum(constant, variable)`) on a `MathObject`, Java will regard its declared type rather than its actual type, throwing an error like: `no suitable method found for...`, summing all operation methods and saying `MathObject` isn't in them.

To clarify `Constant`, `Variable` and all other objects used here naturally extend `MathObject`.
`contains(Variable variable)` is a method to find whether a `Product` already contains the `Variable`.

The idea is to be able to do something like this:

```
new Constant(2).multiply(new Variable(1)).add(new Variable(1)).add(new Constant(1));
```

Here the multiply and the first add operation will work with type specific methods, but the second will fail because the first will return a `MathObject` instead of a specific object and Java doesn't check the actual types for method selection.

These are what the different classes look like:

```
//These are all in different files, silly formatting doesn't allow me to split code sections.
public class Constant extends MathObject{
    public final double c;

    public Constant(double c){
        this.c = c;
    }

    //methods
}

public class Variable extends MathObject{
    public double v;

    public Variable(double v){
        this.v = v;
    }

    //methods
}

public class Sum extends MathObject{
    public MathObject summands;

    public Addition(MathObject... summands){
        this.summands = summands;
    }

    //methods
 }
```

Is there anything I'm missing? Or is this bad practice (and what is the better then)? Is this even possible or am I doomed to the ugly `if` statement chain?

Comment: Where does it throw that error?

Comment: Proper OO would be to invert the call and move the decision what kind of `MathObject` to produce after an `add` to the concrete classes, i.e. `Constant` has a `Constant add(MathObject addend)` method which uses the `if (addend instanceof Constant)`-part, `Variable` has a `MathObject add(MathObject addend)` which uses your `Variable`s `add` method above etc.

Comment: Virtual method are dispatched at runtime, but overloading always happens at compile time, which is why they even think it's a bad idea on its own because it pretends to be a more powerful feature than just allowing `addInteger(int)`, `addFloat(float)`, `addDouble(double)`. If you need this kind of functionality you may find the Visitor pattern useful (basically it will lead to the solution oulined by @Smutje in his comment)

Comment: It's a while ago and I just tried to implement the visitor pattern in such a way that two MathObjects do something like `MathObject add(MathObject that){ return that.add(this); }`. I hoped that that would help them identify eachother but I keep running into the problem that only MathObjects's add is called but not Constant's, even when using one Constant and another as a MathObject. Is there a way to work around that?

Comment: Or am I supposed to implement an accept method for each MathObject, I guess I'll try that next.

Comment: Nope I keep getting the infinite recursions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have the wrong abstractions. You need classes like

```
public interface NumberExpr {
  NumberExpr apply();
  Number get();
}

public class Constant implements NumberExpr {
  final Number val;
}

public class Variable implements NumberExpr {
  final Map<String, Number> symbols;
  final String symbolName;
}

public class Addition implements NumberExpr {
  final NumberExpression op1;
  final NumberExpression op2;
}
```

It's not clear if you need unary and ternary operators, however just consider the simplest binary operations:

```
+ op1 op2
- op1 op2
* op1 op2
/ op1 op2
```

Maybe you have rules for evaluation odrder, precedence and associativity, anyway you'll end up with something like:

```
new Multiplication(
    new Addition(new Variable("counter", ctx), new Variable("i", ctx))
  , new Constant(Math.PI)
)
```

Maybe you first need a step to `.evaluate()` expressions and then `.apply()`, anyway you get the final result simply by calling `.apply()` and then `.get()` on the final result.

Comment: This is not what I'm trying to do, what I'm trying is to do something like this: `new Variable(1).multiply(new Constant(2)).add(new Variable(2)).add(new Constant(1));` (Arbitrary).

Comment: By the way I'm trying to avoid binary operations by using the Sum function on an array rather than a repeated Addition. (I actually renamed Addition to Sum but I forgot about that.)

Comment: Ugly. That way you need to have your own Number supertype and define each and every operation in each and every subclass (by the way, a variable can't be represented by a constant like you do in your last comment)

Comment: Yes it can be represented by a constant, it only differs from a constant because its value is not final. I could link to the source if you'd want me to, but I've got three versions and all are unfinished.

Comment: If you think it's ugly to avoid binary operations I'd say it's better because with binary operations I would have to recurse through the operations to e.g. find matching variables. By making Sum hold an array I can just iterate over it.

Comment: You can structure your program any way you want, but here you a fact: you came up with a problem you can't solve yourself, you posted it on StackOverflow and in two hours nobody came even close to understand what your problem is. Maybe someone someday will be able to solve it (maybe even yourself) - but for now you should at least consider that **you** may be going the wrong way

Comment: What I'm trying, is to tell Java to ignore the declared type of the object and use its actual type to find a suiting method. Or if that's impossible I'm looking for ways to cast an object to it's actual type.

Comment: I already commented on your main question. Anyway, for double dispatch you may find the *Visitor* pattern useful in Java. Basically, your MathContext will have an operation suitable for each type, and each type has a method with a MathContext object as a parameter, that it can call the right method upon